# Vuejs - Focus element check

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <span
      contenteditable="true"
      spellcheck="false"
      style="width: 800px; display: block"
      :v-text="textEl"
      @focus="focused = true"
      @blur="focused = false"
    />
    {{ focused }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      focused: false,
      textEl: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    start() {
      if (this.focused) {
        this.textEl = "text with focus";
      } else {
        this.textEl = "text with not focus";
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.start();
    },
  },
  components: {},
};
</script>
```

[Full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-cerf-ej3fq?file=/src/App.vue).

When the span is focused, I set `focused` to `true`, but, why does the method `start` not run?

I need to show `"text with focus"` when the element is focused, and `"text with not focus"` when the element is not focused. How I can do it? Method `start` doesn't work inside `mounted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is only being called when the component is mounted.

You either need to make `start` a watcher so it runs whenever `focused` changes:

```
watch: {
    focused(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            this.textEl = "text with focus";
        } else {
            this.textEl = "text with not focus";
        }
    }
}
```

Or call `start` in the event-handlers:

```
@focus="start()"
@blur="start()"
...
start() {
    this.focused = !this.focused;

    if (this.focused) {
        this.textEl = "text with focus";
    } else {
        this.textEl = "text with not focus";
    }
},
```

Comment: I need show default: "text with not focus"

Comment: You can set `textEl` to any default text.